# adhesive for vinyl plank stair treads and MDF risers

Tags: stairs, adhesive, vinyl-flooring

I'm redoing stairs with vinyl plank (EVP) treads (with build-in pad), and then 1/2" MDF covers for risers.

What adhesive should I be using for the vinyl plank (with pad)?  What about for the MDF risers?

thanks

Comment: Usually in the install instructions for the product, the manufacturer has the recommended adhesive for the material. Other than that, if it is not available we would need to know the actual product you are installing. For what it is worth, we would most likely look it up online, just like you could. For the risers, the same adhesive may work there too. Pre fit, glue, set in place before the treads.

Comment: it's Coreluxe EVP with pad --- they're designed to be floating, so I wasn't able to find anything about adhesive.